# NodeJs MySQL Login With Hash Password

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I Try With This Login But It Didn't Work,
I Don't Know How To Solve This.

In Register Page I Successfully Enter Hash Password But When I Enter Wrong Password In Login Page ? It Says Login Successfully

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM App WHERE name = '"+ name +"' ", function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        if(rows.length <= 0){
                errors.push({ msg: 'Wrong Username' });
        }else{
            var hash = "SELECT password FROM App WHERE name = '"+ name + "' ";
            connection.query(hash, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                bcryptjs.compare(req.body.pass , hash, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) { throw (err); }
                    console.log(result);
                });
            });
        }
    }
    if(errors.length > 0){
        res.render('login',{
            errors,
            name,
            pass
        });
    }else{
        res.render('Home', { name: name});
    }
});`enter code here`
```

When I Run Its Show False In Terminal

```
**Server is running at localhost:1001

Connected!

false**
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Use *placeholder values* when introducing any sort of data into your query.

Comment: Please don't capitalize every single word. It's very confusing. (Only proper nouns get that sort of treatment.)

Comment: Since it's 2020 it's about time to pick up on how to use JavaScript Promises effectively as they're a core feature of Node now, and make upgrading to the `async`/`await` style super easy. This callback-driven code is very difficult to debug and maintain. [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) is a great database layer that's fully Promise-driven.

Comment: Placeholder Value ? I Mean I used Input Value To Select Password ,

Comment: `"name ='" + name + "'"` is SQL injection and is extremely dangerous. Never do this. Always do something like `"name=?"` and then pass in `name` as a separate argument. Most database drivers for Node allow this, even the basic [MySQL driver](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECE` is surely a typo, so this should be returning an error. You're also capturing the variable `results` and then using `result`, which doesn't match and is also an error.

Since you're testing for the *presence of errors* rather than the presence of a successful test and your code has enough errors it fails to properly populate that array, I suspect you're not picking up on the real error and are presuming everything worked out, which it didn't.

Tip: *Test for a successful outcome, not an absence of failures*.

This is where Promises help. They will automatically explode if errors occur and you don't properly `catch` them.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I Clear Some Typo Mistakes But It Still Didn't Work,

Comment: Like I said, there's a lot of little mistakes here that are holding you up, and identifying and fixing them is made harder because it's all callback-style code. Promises make errors way more obvious, you'll get a console message, not just a quiet failure if you fail to catch it.

Comment: Yes I Also Try To For Successful Outcome But I Get Some Errors That Didn't Show Errors On Ejs Page

Comment: You've really got to kick that habit of capitalizing every word. It's unnerving. I'd suggest writing this as promise style code not just for practice, but to shake out the other problems you're having. It's hard for me to test this code because it requires a lot of set-up to replicate the issues you're having.

Comment: Sorry For My Typing Habbit , I Know About Promises But I Don't Know How To Use Them So I Didn't Use

Comment: The sooner you learn about Promises, the better off you'll be. Writing callback-style code is at least 4x harder, and debugging it is easily 10x harder. Knowing how to use callbacks is important, though, so that learning isn't wasted. You just need to step up to the next level in order to be effective here and shake out those issues.

Comment: You *must* properly chain your callbacks. That is any callback function that receives an error from a callback-function it calls must forward that error or it gets lost. Check that every `err` you have is properly forwarded or at least reported.

Comment: Yes Callbacks Is Harder , It's What I Learned Online And I Used My Way, Problem Is I Didn't Learn Properly

Comment: Promises are a different style of writing code, but once you try it out you'll quickly realize it's way easier to get right. `async`/`await` takes it a step further and makes it even easier to follow.

Comment: Is There Any Other Way Without Promises ?

Comment: Sadly, more debugging. Check you're catching every error which may occur.

Comment: Yes Because I'm New

Comment: I Mean I'm Learning Now

Comment: Im Saying Just How To Compare Login Page Password With Password That Stored In Database With Hash

Comment: `bcryptjs.compareSync` is the correct approach, but you need to be sure that code is actually running, and secondly, that it's receiving the correct arguments.

Comment: I think one of the problems is you're testing for the presence of errors long before any of the callback functions have actually finished. Promise code would help here: `check().then(() => { ... test ... })` makes sequencing things easier. You may want to break this up into functions that makes reading the overall structure more straight-forward even if you're still using callbacks.

Comment: See The Code , When I Try This Method To Compare It Show False In Terminal